# iOS - Navigation Title comes from left when back button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In my app when I visit certain view controllers and touch the Back button in the navigation bar, the navigation title of the resulting viewcontroller looks to be coming from the upper left corner and it looks ugly.

A picture of such an instance is shown below.

[image]

I have set the titles programatically.

Can somebody please tell me why this is happening and how I could fix it? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

ViewController B

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,120,45)] ;
    label.textColor = COLOR_TEXT_NAVIGATION_BAR_COLOR;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = FONT_NAVIGATION_TITLE_BAR;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:PAGE_TITLE_ADD_SERVICE_PROVIDER];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    [label sizeToFit];


    UIButton *homeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
    [homeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_HOME_MENU_BUTTON] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(homeMenuAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:homeButton];


    accNumTextFiled.delegate=self;

    nameTextFiled.text = addPayee.providerName;
    payLimitTextFiled.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%9.2f", addPayee.paymentLimit];//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",addPayee.paymentLimit];
    descTextFiled.text = addPayee.description;
    catTextFiled.text = addPayee.maincategory;
    subCatTextFiled.text = addPayee.subcategory;

    accNumTextFiled.text = addPayee.paymentAccountNumber;

    [accNumTextFiled setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

    [self labelCss];

    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,450);
}
```

ViewController A

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = COLOR_BG_INNER_PAGE_COLOR;


    NSArray *mappingObjArray1  = @[@"providerName",@"description",@"paymentLimit",@"providerCode",@"maincategory",@"subcategory"];

    NSDictionary *queryParams = @{};


    commonRestDataMapping = nil;
    commonRestDataMapping = [[CommonRestDataMapping alloc] init];
    commonRestDataMapping.restDataMappingDelegate = self;
    commonRestDataMapping.servicePath = REST_WEB_SERVICE_ADD_PAYEE_LIST;
    commonRestDataMapping.mappingObjArray = mappingObjArray1;
    commonRestDataMapping.mappingClassString = @"AddPayee";
    commonRestDataMapping.mappingKeyPath = @"data";
    commonRestDataMapping.mappingQueryParams = queryParams;


    [commonRestDataMapping configureRestKit];
    [commonRestDataMapping loadDataArray];


    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [super createNavigationBar:USER_ACCOUNT_PAGE];
    [super setNavihationTitle:PAGE_TITLE_ADD_PAYEE];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];

}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    //WEB service data initilization
    [[WebServiceUrl getSharedInstance] dataiInitialize];

    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyCBfhnMtcmdhJaaqff72PlvJIjBTZpfSu4"];

    NSString* docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString* dbPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datadb.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database is existed.
    if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:dbPath])
    {
        // If database is not existed, copy from the database template in the bundle
        NSString* dbTemplatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"datadb" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSError* error = nil;
        [fm copyItemAtPath:dbTemplatePath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"can't copy db.");
        } else{
            NSLog(@" copy db.");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"  db exsists");
    }


    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
        addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 20);
        addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //change this to match your navigation bar

        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
    }



    homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *myNav1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];


    UIImage *navBackgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aa1.png"];

    [myNav1.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];//iOS 5 only

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = myNav1;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    return YES;
}

- (void)transitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    withTransition:(UIViewAnimationOptions)transition
{
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                        toView:viewController.view
                      duration:0.35f
                       options:transition
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
                    }];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code that might be applicable?

Comment: Hi @Mike, I've added some code.

Comment: Try popViewControllerAnimated Without Animation.

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: @V.J. Tried that, doesn't work. :/

Comment: can you put the code for [super createNavigationBar:USER_ACCOUNT_PAGE];
    [super setNavihationTitle:PAGE_TITLE_ADD_PAYEE];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];